# Proxy external request

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to setup angular to proxy an external API request, not a request that hitting the same base url as where angular is running/hosted.

So angular is running on `http://localhost:4200/` and I want the proxy to catch requests made to `http://foo.bar.baz:8080/api`

The below config doens't work, and fails with this error:

> Error: [HPM] Invalid context. Expecting something like: ["/api", "/ajax"] or ["/api/**", "!**.html"]

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "http://foo.bar.baz:8080/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

I also tried `"*/api/**": {` but got same error. So it seems that the URL has to begin with `/`

How do I move forward?

-- UPDATE --

Here's the HttpClient request:

`this.http.get("http://foo.bar.baz:8080/api")...`

Comment: can you share your service call code

Comment: Sure `this.http.get("http://foo.bar.baz:8080/api")...`

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work :

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
          "^/api": ""
        }
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md).

Comment: target is not `http://foo.bar.baz:8080` but `http://localhost:3000`. See my example config in the OP

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't proxy `this.http.get("http://foo.bar.baz:8080/api")`

Answer (score 0):

Modify Your Code Like this

```
   {
      "/http://foo.bar.baz:8080/api":{
        "target":"http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
      }
    }
```

Change Your service Like This

```
this.http.get("./http://foo.bar.baz:8080/api")
```

Comment: The hole point of using a proxy is to not do that else I can just point it to a json file on the disk with file:// or something like that

Comment: I'm looking for a solution where the code still works when I remove the proxy